# How to open .sln project in winrar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a project , If I open in winrar , This project didn't open . My code editor is visual studio 2019. My code file is inculiding vs 2019 items. is there anyone who can help ?

Error : One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to open a solution that is inside a compressed archive?

Comment: You can't load a project or solution that are in a compressed file. You have to extract the contents to a folder and then open

Comment: VS will open a valid solution/project. If you had a valid solution/project before you compressed it and then it's not when you extract it then the issue is with how to compressed and/or extracted it. That has got nothing to do with VS and, in fact, nothing to do with programming, so it's not a question for this site.

Comment: You can try to extract the rar file to a folder and open the .sln from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to extract the rar file to a folder and open the .sln from there.

Do all the editing in VS 2019 and compress the whole solution into a rar again when it is time to submit homework.

Comment: Of course but ı must upload my homework in winrar . This reason ı need to open in winrar :(

Comment: @superlunary no, you don't need. It's ok to compress the solution folder and upload, but to open you need to extract first. There is no way to load solution/projects without extracting to a folder.

Comment: yes openiing the .sln from the winrar will only extract the .sln file  (without all the source files needed to load and run the solution)